# Access hdfs file from udf

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I`d like to access a file from my udf call. This is my script:

```
files = LOAD '$docs_in' USING PigStorage(';') AS (id, stopwords, id2, file);
buzz = FOREACH files GENERATE pigbuzz.Buzz(file, id) as file:bag{(year:chararray, word:chararray, count:long)};
```

The jar is registered. The path is realtive to my hdfs, where the files really exist. The call is made. But seems that the file is not discovered. Maybe beacause I'm trying to access the file on hdfs.

How can I access a file in hdfs, from my UDF java call?

Comment: Please share your UDF code.

Answer (score 5):

Inside an [EvalFunc](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/EvalFunc.html) you can get a file from the HDFS via:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(UDFContext.getUDFContext().getJobConf());
in = fs.open(new Path(fileName));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
....
```

You might also consider putting the files into the distributed cache, in that case you have to override [getCacheFiles()](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/EvalFunc.html#getCacheFiles%28%29) in your EvalFunc class.

E.g:

```
@Override
public List<String> getCacheFiles() {
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(2);
  list.add("/cache/pig/wordlist1.txt#w1");
  list.add("/cache/pig/wordlist2.txt#w2");
  return list;
}
```

then you can just pass the symlinks of the files (*w1* and *w2*) in order to get them from
the local file system of each of the worker nodes:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```