# Accessing Hadoop Distributed Cache in UDF

Tags: caching, hadoop, apache-pig, distributed-cache

Is it possible to pick up files from the distributed cache in a UDF?

Before diving in further, I spent quite a bit of time trying to find an answer to this particular question (on StackOverflow and otherwise), and was not able to find one.

The main crux of the problem is as follows: I would like to take a file that is already on HDFS, copy it over to the distributed cache in Pig, and then be able to read this file from the cache in a Java UDF. Another hiccup is that due to the design of the program, I am unable to extend from 'EvalFunc', which may solve the issue.

I specified `SET mapred.cache.files '$PATH_TO_FILE_ON_HDFS'` as well as `SET mapped.create.symlink 'yes'` in my Pig script, passed the file path as a parameter to the UDF, and attempted to use FileSystem and FileReader classes to access the file, to no avail.

Please let me know if I can further clarify this/provide any more relevant details.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515284

Comment: It is not quite a duplicate - I cannot use EvalFunc (as I specify in my question).